# database call interupted even with signal handler

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, sigint, sigterm

I have a script that loops infinitely and makes an Oracle call through cx_oracle every X seconds.  I also have a signal handler which should allow the script to exit gracefully after it finishes running the oracle procedure.  The problem I am running into is the oracle call appears to be interupted by a sigint or a sigterm even though I am handling these.

It is throwing the following error: `ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation`

Here is a sample code (trimmed):

```
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        print time.strftime(settings.FDATE) + " - Quitting safely..."
        global exit
        try:
                exit = 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                exit = 1
                print 'Script is quitting safely, please wait...'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

while not exit:
    #database call here
    sleep 5 #actually taking this value from a settings file
```

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I am also multithreading based on the results of the database call but the error still happens within the main while loop.

Comment: Look at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet-ora-file.html#GUID-3F3AC8BD-F643-427A-BD6A-9B88CF42B972

Comment: @ChristopherJones That actually fixed my problem.  If you write it in an answer I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: Never mind, I'm still seeing the error in the log.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that Oracle does use SININT to cancel the current operation.  To avoid conflict you may want to consider using other signals such as SIGQUIT or SIGSTOP.

Comment: SIGINT is thrown by unix to kill a service.  I do not have control over this.